# Concat two columns from mysql and display distinct values in dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code to combine the two columns data and display distinct values in the dropdown list:

```
<?php

    include_once "connect.php";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 
    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT A, B FROM Contracts WHERE something='Ssomething' as amount"); 
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
       echo "<option value='" .  $row['amount'] . " " . $row['amount'] . "</option>"; 
    }
    $conn->db=null;

?>
```

I get the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in xyz line 5.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `var_dump($stmt);` before the `while` You will see something interesting.

Answer (score 2):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in xyz line 5.
>
> Normally means the query has failed and returned FALSE into your `$stmt` object.

In this case the query syntax is incorrect, if you code some error checking it will tell you what the error actually is

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 

$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(A,B) as amount FROM Contracts WHERE something='Ssomething'"); 
if ( $stmt === FALSE ) {
    print_r($conn->errorInfo());
    exit;
}

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
   echo "<option value='" .  $row['amount'] . " " . $row['amount'] . "</option>"; 
}
$conn->db=null;
?>
```

The error in the query is due to the use of `something='Ssomething' as amount` because you cannot use an alias in a selection criteria.

So try

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(A,B) as amount FROM Contracts WHERE something='Ssomething'
```

as your query. But the distinct would then become unnecessary/irrelevant.

Comment: What are the data types of the columns A and B and did you mean to add them or concatenate them

Comment: concatenate them... one is numbers other words

Comment: Then I will remove the `A+B` suggestion as that is not what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, B FROM Contracts WHERE something='Ssomething' as amount
```

You will need to use a specific concat function in mysql.

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(A, B) as amount
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT A, B FROM Contracts WHERE something='Ssomething') x
```

Comment: Sounds like a PHP issue, have you read through this (defining the variable names)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017682/pdo-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-on-a-non-object

Comment: is Ssomething supposed to be $something

Comment: No. and yes i know it is a php issue hence the question