# Getting fetchAll() error using on Ubuntu

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, pdo

I am trying to fetch data from a remote MSSQL Server. I am using WampServer on Windows 7 64bit Professional. My connection string is as follows:

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server='.$host.';Database=' . $db, $user, $pass, 
               array(
                     PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                     PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                    )
             );
```

I can successfully connect from my local computer and execute queries with this connection.  Then I have uploaded my source to server which runs on Ubuntu 14.04 TLS. I got **0-no driver-found** error. After that I have searched that this connection string is invalid for Ubuntu. I have updated it to

```
 $pdo = new PDO('odbc:Driver=freetds; Server=1.2.3.4; Port=1433; Database=myDB; UID=myUser; PWD=myPass;');
```

After a few configuration, I could have succeeded to connect to the database with no error. But after querying then I try to use PDO's `fetchAll()` method I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

The code is the same with I always use. I think this is because of connection. But I do not know what to do next?

EDIT:

I can run this script on my local computer with no error. But it does not work on Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349612/pdo-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-on-a-non-object)

Comment: _I can run this script on my local computer with no error_ os ?

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant I use Windows 7 Pro x64 on my local computer

Comment: If on loca you use Windows, check UPPERCASE caracter maybe table 'user' and you write 'User'

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant no it is not a uppercase-lowercase issue. I have checked it for a few times.

Comment: @Pete you are awesome. Thanks. I am going to undelete my question, if I can.